# TIMEDIFF Subquery returns more than 1 row in mariadb

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, mariadb

Having an issue with a specific section of a query using **TIMEDIFF** And **ADDTIME**:

i want to the result like this :

```
| waktuhilang |
|-------------|
|    04:00:00 |
|    03:00:00 |

SELECT
ADDTIME(
    (
        SELECT
            SEC_TO_TIME(
                SUM(
                    TIME_TO_SEC(
                        maketime(
                            durasi + 0,
                            substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0,
                            0
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) waktudw
        FROM
            trans_lhpdtdw
    ),
    (
        SELECT
            TIMEDIFF(JamMasuk, JamMulai) lamaistirahat
        FROM
            trans_lhphd
    )
) waktuhilang
```

I've seen some people mentioning using IN instead of = within the subquery, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas out there? Thanks

I have two tables :

[Table trans_lhpdtdw](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24813/4) 
[Table trans_lhphd](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddc3ce/1)

```
CREATE TABLE `trans_lhpdtdw` (
  `IdBukti` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PartID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `TypeDowntime` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Durasi` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `KeteranganDowntime` longtext NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of trans_lhpdtdw
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `trans_lhpdtdw` VALUES ('2', 'BLAP-FG150-KT-KGX', 'SETTING MOLD', '1 Jam 0 Menit', 'ass');
INSERT INTO `trans_lhpdtdw` VALUES ('1', 'BLAP-FG152-PF-KGX', 'TIDAK ADA FASILITAS', '1 Jam 0 Menit', 'as');
INSERT INTO `trans_lhpdtdw` VALUES ('1', 'AWDX-FG002-HN-KGX', 'TIDAK ADA JOB', '2 Jam 0 Menit', 'sasa');

CREATE TABLE `trans_lhphd` (
  `IdBukti` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NoBukti` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `Periode` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `Tanggal` date NOT NULL,
  `Divisi` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `JamKerja` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `JamProduksi` time NOT NULL,
  `JamSelesai` time NOT NULL,
  `JamMulai` time NOT NULL,
  `JamMasuk` time NOT NULL,
  `IdMesin` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `LineID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Operator` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Planning` decimal(18,0) NOT NULL,
  `Tambahan` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdBukti`),
  KEY `IdBukti` (`IdBukti`),
  KEY `IdBukti_2` (`IdBukti`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of trans_lhphd
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `trans_lhphd` VALUES ('1', 'LHP/201708/00001', '201708', '2017-08-24', 'ALL DIVISI IMPORT (NON PPIC)', 'Shift I', '01:05:00', '09:05:00', '01:00:00', '02:00:00', 'BH 260K', 'L3002', '1', '213', '1 Jam 15 Menit');
INSERT INTO `trans_lhphd` VALUES ('2', 'LHP/201708/00002', '201708', '2017-08-17', 'INJECTION', 'Shift I', '07:00:00', '16:00:00', '11:25:00', '13:25:00', 'BH 260K', 'L2002', '100', '1000', '');
```

Comment: Any subquery within a SELECT clause can ONLY return a SINGLE VALUE. How many rows are in the table **trans_lhphd**?  So the second subquery will most likely break the single value rule won't it?

Comment: there are 2 rows or more than one row,

Comment: Exactly! So that second subquery will attempt to return many rows, but the rule is: **Any subquery within a SELECT clause can ONLY return a SINGLE VALUE.** Try the solution by Gordon Linoff below, he may have suggested the needed correction.

Comment: his solution gives me same result even tough more than one row. because in the tabel **trans_lhpdtdw** . there is more than one row

Comment: So the "same result" with more rows it isn't what you want? The problem for us is we cannot see any data or any result; just a query that does not work. **Provide some sample of data from each table**, then specify **what the result should be**. Do this by editing the question, don't try to add data into a comment. Use simple parsable text (not images) for the data - or setup your example at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: by the way, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it will help you understand why we need sample data and expected result (& you will get faster answers if you do provide "a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example").

Comment: i have edited my question, and gives link to view my table. Maybe you can help again

Comment: Thanks. (Note you can include both tables into a single sqlfiddle.) But I still have no "vision" of what you expect as the result. are you seeking **just one value** called waktuhilang?

Comment: always add the sample data into the question as text. sometime sqlfiddle breaks down so you need the data as a direct part of the question so others can use it to help answer

Comment: There are 3 indexes on `IdBukti`; you need only 1; keep the PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach providing one row for each IdBukti

**Query**:

```
SELECT
   d.IdBukti, ADDTIME(w.waktudw, TIMEDIFF(d.JamMasuk, d.JamMulai)) waktuhilang
FROM trans_lhphd as d
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT IdBukti, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0, substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0, 0)))) waktudw
           FROM trans_lhpdtdw
           GROUP BY IdBukti
           ) as w ON d.IdBukti = w.IdBukti
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13a7b/4/0)**:

```
| IdBukti | waktuhilang |
|---------|-------------|
|       1 |    04:00:00 |
|       2 |    03:00:00 |
```

Comment: Please note that it was the following small comment that enabled me to write the solution *"i want to the result is more than one row with same IdBukti in each table"* until that explanation was available there was simply no way to know what you expected. Next time you ask a question do include the "expected result"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the second subquery.  I am guessing that you want:

```
SELECT ADDTIME( (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,
                                                  substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0, 0
                                                            )
                                                   )
                                       )
                                   )
                 FROM trans_lhpdtdw
                ),
                TIMEDIFF(JamMasuk, JamMulai)
              ) as waktuhilang
FROM trans_lhphd;
```

Comment: no your result is same. i've ever used "where"  but it gives me one row even tough there are 2 rows or more than 1 row

Comment: because in the tabel **trans_lhpdtdw** . there is more than one row

Comment: i have edited my question, and gives link to view my table. Maybe you can help again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want just one value returned by your query, adjust the second subquery to return the SUM of the TIMEDIFF calculations.

Also refer to this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13a7b/1)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
 ADDTIME(
         (
           SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0, substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0, 0)))) waktudw
           FROM trans_lhpdtdw
         )
        , (
           SELECT SUM(TIMEDIFF(JamMasuk, JamMulai)) 
           FROM trans_lhphd
         )
       ) waktuhilang
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13a7b/1/0)**:

```
| waktuhilang |
|-------------|
|    07:00:00 |
```

Comment: is this what you expected? *using SUM() of the time differences*

Comment: your result is one row , even tough my data is more than one row. i want to the result is more than one row with same IdBukti in each table. so the result is different

Comment: So, as I have asked many times.... add the "expected result" into your question. When we see that we will know what it is you are asking for.